# Prepend match number to output match lines of grep?

Tags: grep

Say I have this file, `test.log`:

```
blabla test test
20 30 40
hello world
100 100
34 506 795
blabla test2
50 60 70
hello
10 10
200 200
blabla test BB
30 40 50
100 100
20 20 20 20
```

I would like to print all lines with `blabla` in them, the line after that - with the match number prepended.

Without match number, it is easy:

```
$ grep -A1 "blabla" test.log
blabla test test
20 30 40
--
blabla test2
50 60 70
--
blabla test BB
30 40 50
```

With a prepended match number, it would look like this:

```
1: blabla test test
1: 20 30 40
--
2: blabla test2
2: 50 60 70
--
3: blabla test BB
3: 30 40 50
```

The tricky part is, I want to preserve the match number, regardless if I just grep for a single line match, or with context (X lines after or before the match).

Is there an easy way to do this? If I could do a format specifier for the number, as in `%03d`, even better - but just a usual number would be fine too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
 grep -A1 blahblah test.log | awk -v n=1 '$0 == "--" { n += 1; print; next }
                                          { printf("%03d: %s\n", n, $0) }'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works - and it preserves separators, and has number formatting; except, as it is, the command will not work with the example in OP, because the match is `blabla`, not `blahblah`'; also a note: this pattern will work also if everything is on one line instead of two

Comment: @sdbbs You'd obviously replace blahblah with the actual regular expression being used.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne '/blabla/ and print ++$i, ":$_" and print "$i:", scalar <>' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- each line is read into the special variable `$_`
- the diamond operator `<>` reads the next line from the input file
- [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) makes it read just one line, not all the remaining ones
- the variable `$i` is incremented each time `blabla` is encountered and is prepended to each output line.

Your specification doesn't handle the case when two `blabla`s are present on adjacent lines.

To format the numbers, use [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf):

```
perl -ne 'if (/blabla/) { $f = sprintf "%03d", ++$i; print $f, ":$_"; print "$f:", scalar <>}'
```

Comment: Many thanks - works great! Accepted the other answer because it also had number formatting...